# npm doesn't install devDependencies content on ci server

Tags: ember.js, npm, continuous-integration, codeship

I have a private Ember.js project which I am trying to build on CodeShip continuous integration server. To do so I need to install ember-cli which is in my devDependencies. When I do a fresh clone of my project on my machine and `npm install` I get ember-cli binary in `./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember`.

However on the CI server, I have only following files in `node_modules/ember-cli/`:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 rof rof  40K Jun  1 15:15 CHANGELOG.md
drwxrwxr-x 105 rof rof 2.1K Jun  2 13:50 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 rof rof 4.1K Mar  6 23:56 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 rof rof 6.7K Feb 13 17:22 README.md
```

Running npm install --verbose I have following lines in log:

```
npm WARN package.json ember-cli@2.4.2 No bin file found at ./bin/ember
...
npm verb already installed skipping ember-cli@2.4.2 /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/xxx/yyy
```

And similar lines for other devDependencies.

I have checked that `NODE_ENV` is empty and `npm config get production` is false. I have also checked that I am using same node (0.12.2) and npm (2.7.4) versions on local machine and CI server.

So my question is: why it works on local machine, but doesn't work on CI server? Is there some configuration value that is missing?

Comment: Check the NODE_ENV variable.  I ran into the same problem on heroku, and had to pass in the --dev in the npm install step.

Comment: `NODE_ENV` is empty, as I wrote in the question, and `--dev` is not an option because it install devDependencies recursively, which takes ages in my case